# How to upload an image url in google plus using api php?

Tags: php, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to upload an image to google plus using api in php. This is the api that I'm trying to access
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/plusDomains/v1/people/".$unique_id."/media/cloud

And passing header like this:

```
"Authorization: OAuth $ACCESS_TOKEN"
"Content-Type: image/jpeg"
```

And passing image url as parameter. But I'm getting this error:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badContent",
"message": "Media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported. Valid media types: [image/*, video/*]"
```

Anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: Google+ api is not the Google plus domains api please remember to tag things corectly

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying it via postman. And whenever I'm accessing it through the code, it returns "Bad content type. Please use multipart." error.